Perception and likeness can not be particle-intrinsic, can they? Where do perceptions exist?
You can put circuitry together just as the brain does.
But which components of the circuitry perform what exact task and why if they are fiercly indiscriminate?
Sure there may be color neurons, facial neurons, neurons that correlate with letters or integers.
Here's the twist: They are all of the same material and same specification. So what tells which does which?
You can argue arrangement of the neurons dictates the function.
Is arrangement a field?
Is arrangement a particle?
Is there an arrangement particle that determines?
Isn't arrangement a pattern of relations of matter? But what type of matter is a pattern? It gets circular...
You cant even compare to a CPU, as sure it may apparently have distinct patterns and one and the same transistor as functional unit...
But it does not have what appears qualia that exists in an apparently parallel dimension of reality?
Singular neurons don't seem to either.
Do perceptions arise from a field?
That should interact with electromagnetism, plus it should parse electric depolarizations into this likeness.

It is a complex process (still partly unknown): we have to consider not only "particles", but also structure and function. Also human are made "only" of cells, but there are some compelx aggregations of them that digest while others walk.

That's the thing. Externally we observe matter and relations of matter. For what is going on in perception, relations then become the new matter. How and why...

Is this about the Jennifer Aniston neuron ?

Yes, inspired by such, and singular facial recognition neurons in the fusiform gyrus.

The field of perception is the whole shebang of existence. Maybe specific features like visual faces are imprinted somewhere localised, but they would be details on a symphony of existential generation.  There wouldn't be a neuron for the existence of spoons.  There is existence, then there is spoon recognition.

Is this a philosophical question?

Or it's a biological question with partial answers.

You can use transistors as an analogy. All modern electronic devices are made up of transistors; how they function is due to how they're all connected. In the brain, this is called the "connectome".

@Barmar Sure, but graph theory doesn't get you anywhere if you want to explain why neurons firing in one part of the brain give rise to the smell of cinnamon, but neurons firing in another part of the brain evokes the sensation of the colour red... Good call though.

I attempt to focus your several question into one single question:

Which concepts from physics are good candidates as the basis for
neuroscientific models of the neuronal correlate of qualia (=
likeness)  and conscious perception in general?


“Particle” is not a good candidate: All neurons are collections of
particles. Different chemical ions are relevant for the operating
of their membranes to produce an electric stimulus. Thinking in particles
is relevant for the deep layer of neurobiology, not for the
high-level phenomena of the OP’s question.

“Field” – like the electromagnetic field – is the basic concept to
describe interaction in electromagnetism and current quantum field
theory in general. Also this concept does not seem essential for
neuroscicence of conscioous perceptions. Mental processes act on the basis of electric
charges and their currents.

“Arrangement particle”: Possibly this term has be been coined by the
OP.
In any case, the brain operates in a distributed way. Even when
one can distinguish hierachical layers, there is no single
distinct instance which makes the decision. The genesis of the
brain during the ontogenesis of the individuum is by
self-organisation, caused by genetic inheritance and personal
biography.

“Circuitry” is a first approximation to the network of neural
communication. Neuroscience investigates and identifies fixed
circuitries. They often show a high degree of feedback loops.

A relevant basic concept from physics is the “temporal pattern” of
synchronized electric activity. A first step in the investigation was the development of EEGs (electroencephalogram). Besides single-unit recording currently
neuroscience operates with medical imaging, e.g., fMRI.


Currently, the idea of the neuronal correlate of consciousness (NCC) is to relate conscious experience (first-person stance) to the synchronized activity of distinct brain areas (third-person stance).
While to approach the problem of consciousness simply with the basic  concept of particles seems outdated and a blind alley.

All computers are made of similar material. And yet, we use them to make distinctions between wildly different kinds of objects. Why can’t the same be done for the brain?
You are simply engaging in a fallacy that distinctions can’t be created by a substrate that is fundamentally one material.
